# Count once time smilar id in sql

Tags: sql

My aim is to count according to the `id`  once time same id It doesn't count every `id` each time.

I used this:

```
Select count Where id=1 between 1000;
```

but it counts to smilar `id`  more than one.

Comment: try `select count (distinct id) where id between 1 and 1000`

Comment: Most probably not relevant here, but you should always tag your question with the relevant DBMS: Postgres, Oracle, DB2, Firebird, ...

Comment: @Ridvan I am not sure whether its relevant here or not but You are counting distinct Id where you know min and max limit ! Not sure why you are writing query for it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `DISTINCT`

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT id)
FROM YourTable
WHERE id BETWEEN 1 AND 1000
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you try this :
`Count with ID` like this

```
SELECT COUNT(ID) FROM dbo.TableName WHERE ID BETWEEN 1 AND 1000
```